# Fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

i'm stuck in my application because i have to do a fragment with the navigation drawer in kotlin.. can anyone help? I have search a lot of things in web but i didn't find anything yet...
Down here is two items that i have do in main activity and i want  that is present in the fragment too.

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.home -> {

        }
        R.id.subjects -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, SubjectsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Comment: A fragment resides in an Activity so if you have the navigation drawer in the Activity it will be there in the Fragment also, considering that that Activity holds that Fragment

Comment: So i can add a new activity with navigation drawer and put them as a fragment?

Comment: Create an Activity with navigation drawer and add a Fragment to that Activity, it should work.

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  <---- is in this i have to add a fragment?

Comment: Does MainActivity contain the navigation drawer? if yes, yes

Comment: Your only question in your post is "can anyone help?". You have not specified with what you need help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to do a fragment with navigation drawer and add that fragment to a few activities

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to replace your frame with HomeFragment() 
mainDisplayFrame should be replace by your FrameID

```
var fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainDisplayFrame,HomeFragment()).commit()
mDrawerLayout!!.closeDrawers()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source link from here([Navigation Drawer In Android Kotlin](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2018/01/navigation-drawer-in-android-kotlin.html))

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        tv_home.setText("Home Tab")
        tv_title.setText("Home")
        ll_about.setOnClickListener(this)
        ll_home.setOnClickListener(this)
        ll_bookmark.setOnClickListener(this)
        ll_help.setOnClickListener(this)
        rl_menu.setOnClickListener(this)
        rl_header.setOnClickListener(this)

        tv_link.setLinkTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        Linkify.addLinks(tv_link, Linkify.ALL)

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when (p0?.id) {

            R.id.ll_home -> {
                drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                tv_home.setText("Home Tab")
                tv_title.setText("Home")


            }
            R.id.ll_about -> {

                val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/"))
                startActivity(browserIntent)

            }

            R.id.ll_help -> {
                drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                tv_home.setText("Help Tab")
                tv_title.setText("Help")

            }

            R.id.ll_bookmark -> {
                drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                tv_home.setText("Bookmark Tab")
                tv_title.setText("Bookmark")

            }

            R.id.rl_header -> {
            }

            R.id.rl_menu -> {
                if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                } else {
                    drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this? @NongthonbamTonthoi

```
class NavViewFragment : AppCompatActivity(), 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int){
    supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(frameId, fragment) }
}



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_view_fragment)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_view, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> return true
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.home -> {

        }
        R.id.subjects -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, SubjectsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        }
    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
    }
inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit) {
    val fragmentTransaction = beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.func()
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}

}
```