# How to change Fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I'm starting in Kotling and I don't know how to change between fragments, I have tried this code:

```
val manager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(R.layout.fragment_information.toInt(), ComplainFragment())
    transaction.commit()
```

> R.layout.fragment_information.toInt()

But i have an error with this parameter because it doesn't find the fragment Id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248840/fragment-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually use replace to change between fragments. Also change  R.layout.fragment_information to R.id.fragment_layout_id only, so no need toInt()

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout_id, fragment)
```

Here is my suggestion.

```
    var fragment: Fragment? = null

            when (itemId) {
                        R.id.fragment_information -> {
                            fragment = ComplainFragment()
                        }
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout_id, fragment)
                    transaction.commit()
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an example for you to go to a fragment or activity by clicking a button inside another fragment:

```
class Fragment_One: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btn_goToActivity2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_goToFragment2.setOnClickListener {
            var fr = getFragmentManager()?.beginTransaction()
            fr?.replace(R.id.fragment, Fragment_Two())
            fr?.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers will work but still we can improve a lot by using extension functions in Kotlin.

Add an extension function to the FragmentManager class like below,

```
inline fun FragmentManager.doTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> 
FragmentTransaction) {
    beginTransaction().func().commit()
}
```

then create an extension function to the AppCompatActivity class,

```
fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(frameId: Int, fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.doTransaction { add(frameId, fragment) }
}


fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(frameId: Int, fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.doTransaction{replace(frameId, fragment)}
}

fun AppCompatActivity.removeFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.doTransaction{remove(fragment)}
}
```

Now, to add and remove fragments from any activity, you just need to call like this,

```
addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)

replaceFragment(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
```

please refer the below link for more info,

https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-kotlin-way-73203c5a450b

Comment: This is the best answer but im curious how can I add this function to fragmentManager class if its Read Only. i have this fun in mainActivity but how can I call it in kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still needs a quick approach to this. I created a function than can be easily called whenever you need to change a fragment.

```
 private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

*R.id.frame* in this case is the id of my Framelayout in the activity that will hold my fragment. All you have to do now is call the function.

```
replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a fragment, you need to add it to an ID that exists in your Activity's layout, not an entire layout:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.some_id_in_your_activity_layout, ComplainFragment()).commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun transitionFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transition = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transition.replace(R.id.fragment_container_create_void_parent, fragment)
              .addToBackStack(null).commit()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[fragment-ktx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) jetpack library contains convenient extension functions which simplify many things, [including transactions](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment):

```kotlin
// MyActivity.kt

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  ...

  fun showMyFragment() {
    val fragment = MyFragment()
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
      replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
    }
  }
}
```

`R.id.fragment_container` it's an id of a fragment container in the parent layout. There's [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView) which is the [recommended](https://amryousef.me/new-in-androidx-fragment#fragmentcontainerview-vs-framelayout) container, for example:

```xml
<!-- my_activity_layout.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        ... />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But if your purpose is to implement in-app navigation, it's better and much easier to use [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) instead of manually switching fragments.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for Change current fragment to orther in kotlin:

```
val supportFragment = SupportFragment()
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                 .add(this.id, supportFragment)
                 .addToBackStack("ok")
                 .commit()
```